# How to create an additional row of square blocks using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Newbie here and in java script.
I am trying to create 5 rows and 5 columns of block of squares but I can only manage to create one row. Can I ask what is missing with my code? Appreciate the help.

```
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  y += 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < + 5; j++) {
        drawGridBoard(x, y, 50, 50)
        x = 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're imcrementing y by nothing: `y += 0;` . Try turning the 0 into a 50.

Comment: thanks! I adjusted the values but the output was a staircase of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your loops.

The outer loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  y += 0;
}
```

increments **i** until it's 5 and with each loop it increments y by nothing

The inner loop:

```
for (let j = 1; j < + 5; j++) {
    drawGridBoard(x, y, 50, 50)
    x = 50;
}
```

increments **j** until it's 5, calls `drawGridBoard` with parameters **x** and **y** and finally sets **x** to 50.

If we replace `drawGridBoard()` by `console.log(x,y);` we can see what's going on:

```
0,0
50,0
50,0
50,0
50,0
50,0
```

As you can see x and y will stay at 50 and respectively. Why? Because you don't use the for-loops variables **i** and **j** to calculate the appropriate screen positions.

With each increment of `j` we want to shift the x position 50 pixels to the right

```
x + j * 50
```

With each increment of `i` we want to shift the y position 50 pixels down

```
y + i * 50
```

Putting it all together:

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawGridBoard(x, y, width, height) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    drawGridBoard(x + j * 50, y + i * 50, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```